# Git launches mergetool without any arguments

Tags: git, git-merge, msysgit

On machine A, `git mergetool` runs Beyond Compare 3 as expected. On machine B, BC3 starts but isn't passed any arguments on the command line, thus showing the intro screen instead of the actual merge.

I copied the config from machine A to machine B, and `git config --list` is identical apart from the installation path and `push.default=simple`:

```
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3='C:/Apps/BeyondCompare3/BCompare.exe'
mergetool.bc3.cmd='C:/Apps/BeyondCompare3/BCompare.exe'
mergetool.bc3.path=C:\Apps\BeyondCompare3\bcomp.exe
push.default=simple
```

The only other differences are that machine A has git 1.7.11 under Win7 64-bit, while machine B (the one that doesn't work) has git 1.8.4 under Win8 32-bit.

ProcessHacker shows that the command line on machine A (for the *exact same* repository, bit for bit) is:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\bcomp.exe" 
        ./somefile.cs.LOCAL.4192.cs 
        ./somefile.cs.REMOTE.4192.cs
        ./somefile.cs.BASE.4192.cs
        -mergeoutput=somefile.cs /BCompWnd=$00140644
```

while on the broken machine B it's simply:

```
c:\Apps\BeyondCompare3\BCompare.exe
```

Which magic incantation do I need here?

Comment: Why is config the same between machines while the tool is in different folders?

Comment: @CharlesB like I said, the config "is identical apart from the installation path" of the tool, sorry if that wasn't clear. The path is different, everything else is identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess: if Git already (in its factory configuration) knows about bc3 tool, it will use `mergetool.bc3.path` along with standard arguments. If not, it looks for `mergetool.bc3.cmd`, but this one needs to have the correct arguments indicated in the command:

```
mergetool.bc3.cmd="'c:/apps/BeyondCompare3/bcomp.exe' '$LOCAL' '$REMOTE' '$BASE' '$MERGED'"
```

For an obscure reason, on machine B Git doesn't know invocation of `bc3`, and falls back using `mergetool.bc3.cmd` which in your case misses the correct arguments. On machine A, Git knows how to talk to BC3, and will use the correct invocation of the tool, using only `mergetool.bc3.path`.

To validate this delete respectively `mergetool.bc3.cmd` and `mergetool.bc3.path` on machine A and B, the behaviours should be exactly the same as you observe.

To fix it, use the complete invocation on `mergetool.bc3.cmd`.

Comment: Alright, this worked. If I remove both `cmd` and `path`, both machines report they can't find BC3. If I remove `cmd` but leave `path`, both machines work. So it appears that machine A worked in the original set-up only because git completely ignored `mergetool.bc3.cmd`. Oh also, `mergetool.bc3` itself appears to be unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: You probably have a `[mergetool "bc3"]` entry on machine A, but not on machine B. Try on both machines: `git config --global --edit`.